# Problem connection wso2 apim 2.6 to wso2 apim 3.2

Tags: wso2, api-manager

I want to add an api published on wso2 apim version 3.2 to apim v2.6.
I failed to do this.
Any idea?

Comment: You can't import/export API projects between two product versions. One option is to take the Swagger of the API and recreate the API again in the other product version

Comment: Thank you for your reply.my problem is that the endpoint url of the api that i want to create on apim v2.6 is an url generated from the client apim v3.2